# How to sort Option List in alphabetical order in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Beginner at JavaScript and ReactJs.
I'm trying to sort this list while displaying options on the front end.

```
  <Select
                value={Reactivity}
                options={[
                  { label: "Chicken", value: "Chicken" },              
                  { label: "Rat", value: "Rat" },
                  { label: "Dog", value:"Dog"},
                  { label: "Pig", value:"Pig"},
                ]}
                placeholder="Reactivity"
                onChange={(v) => {
                  setReactivity(v.map((vv) => vv));
                }}
                isClearable
                isMulti
    />
```

// Code to display and choose options

Comment: btw if you are hardcoding it why dont you write it sorted anyway. if its from a db or something try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort array of objects by string property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value)

Comment: Yes, they're coming from a DB but I'm entering the options manually which is not optimal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Array.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

```js
<Select
    value={Reactivity}
    options={[
        { label: "Chicken", value: "Chicken" },              
        { label: "Rat", value: "Rat" },
        { label: "Dog", value:"Dog"},
        { label: "Pig", value:"Pig"},
    ].sort((a, b) => a.label.localeCompare(b.label))}
    placeholder="Reactivity"
    onChange={(v) => {
        setReactivity(v.map((vv) => vv));
    }}
    isClearable
    isMulti
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read more about [sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and [localeCompare()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare).

You can do something like this :

```
<Select
    value={Reactivity}

    options={() => [
        { label: "Chicken", value: "Chicken" },              
        { label: "Rat", value: "Rat" },
        { label: "Dog", value:"Dog"},
        { label: "Pig", value:"Pig"},
       ].sort((a, b) => a.label.localeCompare(b.label))
    }
    placeholder="Reactivity"

    onChange={(v) => {
        setReactivity(v.map((vv) => vv));
    }}
    isClearable
    isMulti
/>
```